# Add Users Manually Using Google Firebase Without Registering using an Authentication

Tags: android, firebase

I want to know If it can be possible to add users in database manually without asking them to login. Is  there a special way of doing such?

Comment: Asking for a response as soon as possible is not appreciated here on Stack Overflow. Aside from that, this sounds like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem): what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Thanks for the correction, I only want to create android login and reset activity page in java without having to do with registration. In place of registration the developer takes the details of users by sending the the password

Comment: Sounds good. What's keeping you from doing this?